# How to create per-vertex normals when reusing vertex data?

Tags: opengl-es, normals, vertex-arrays

I am displaying a cube using a vertex buffer object (gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER). This allows me to specify vertex *indicies*, rather than having duplicate vertexes. In the case of displaying a simple cube, this means I only need to have eight vertices total. Opposed to needing three vertices per triangle, times two triangles per face, times six faces. Sound correct so far?

My question is, how do I now deal with vertex attribute data such as color, texture coordinates, and normals when reusing vertices using the vertex buffer object?

If I am reusing the same vertex data in my indexed vertex buffer, how can I differentiate when vertex X is used as part of the cube's front face versus the cube's left face? In both cases I would like the surface normal and texture coordinates to be different. I understand I *could* average the surface normal, however I would like to render a cube. Also, this still doesn't work for texture coordinates.

Is there a way to save memory using a vertex buffer object while being able to provide different vertex attribute data based on context? (Per-triangle would be idea.)

Or should I just duplicate each vertex for each context in which it gets rendered. (So there is a one-to-one mapping between vertex, normal, color, etc.)

Note: I'm using OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't -- you can't have differently-sized attribute streams (you'd need multiple index buffers, or some other kind of mapping to correlate them all).

You'll have to duplicate the vertices you want to participate in different triangles or otherwise have unique attributes other than position. This isn't actually as bad *in practice* as it seems in terms of duplication of the position data. A cube is actually a pretty pathological case for this scenario, and tends to make the amount of duplication you'll end up with *seem* much higher than it would be for "real" models. Unless you're game is all about cubes, in which case, well... sorry. :D

Answer (score 0):

Interpolating the normal is fine for the vast majority of real cases.

Plus, cubes have their own special textures, cube maps, with 3D texture co-ordinates. In conjunction with a normal map, you shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

One way to 'solve' this is to use a normal texture and look up the normal for each pixel in the fragment shader. Hopefully this should be possible with OpenGL ES.

It might be a bit overkill to have normal mapping with cubes but for real models I suppose they work out just fine.